# How to create ActiveTabChanged for Ajax tabContainer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

How to create ActiveTabChanged for Ajax tabContainer? If it was a Button, just double click to create the code below. I double clicked the tabContainer but nothing happened.

I also have a related question, please click this link: 
[[Ajax tabContainer using GridView inside panel, one button outside of the tabContainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25024538/ajax-tabcontainer-using-gridview-inside-panel-one-button-outside-of-the-tabcont][1])

My .aspx code: notice I've changed to AutoPostBack="True"

Splash

Comment: you add AutoPostBack="true"

Comment: Hi, I've added thanks but still not appearing.  My sorce code:                 <ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabConAddInfo" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" AutoPostBack="True">

Comment: share your code of aspx page

Comment: <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
                <ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabConAddInfo" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" AutoPostBack="True">
                    <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="tapSplash" HeaderText="Splash"  runat="server"><HeaderTemplate>&Splash</HeaderTemplate>
                        <ContentTemplate>                     
                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" >

Comment: sorry i cant edit my question now but the above is partial of my coding. notice the  AutoPostBack="True" has changed. thanks.

Comment: hey your problem is solved or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) first you select your tab container

2) after press f4 then

3) go to event

4) double click on ActiveTabChanged

Comment: Hi, sorry. I had to sleep coz I'm in New Zealand time. Will try little later and will let you know. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hiral, I'm so sorry but when i press f4, it shows me properties and I can't find "event". I only can see "Enabled" "Enable Theming" "EnableViewState" under (Expressions). FYI, I'm using Windows in Macbook, is that why the f4 key directed me to wrong place? coz the some keys doesn't work accordingly in Mac....OH! I see "OnClientActiveTabChanged" but double clicking doesn't work, I need to type in something. What do I need to type? Thank you a lot!

Comment: Sorry for the late comment! It worked beautifully~ :)