# Ajax tabContainer using panel, one button outside of the tabContainer

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I'm creating Admin Panel using Ajax tab container which has 5 tapPanels and in that each tapPanel, I have one Panel from standard tool. And in that each Panel, I have GridView to show added data. And finally, I have one Add button outside of the Ajax tabContainer. I'll post the design if it allows. The problem is, I don't know the coding for tabContainer. I've created 10 methods so I can call it when Add button clicks.

Here is my code which is not working.

```
namespace Admin_Panel
{
    public partial class add : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["Page"] = "ADD";           
        }

        protected void btnAddCat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer container = (AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer)TabConAddInfo;
            AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel tcTabPanel = new AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel();

            if (tcTabPanel.HeaderText == "Splash")
            {
                addSplash();
                lblMsgAdd.Text = "Added successfully";
            }
            else if (tcTabPanel.HeaderText == "Main Category")
            {
                addMainCat();
                lblMsgAdd.Text = "Added successfully";
            }
            else if (tcTabPanel.HeaderText == "Sub Category")
            {
                addSubCat();
                lblMsgAdd.Text = "Added successfully";
            }
            else if (tcTabPanel.HeaderText == "Business Contact")
            {
                addBusinessContact();
                lblMsgAdd.Text = "Added successfully";
            }
            else if (tcTabPanel.HeaderText == "Person Contact")
            {
                addPersonContact();
                lblMsgAdd.Text = "Added successfully";
            }            
        }

       Int32 fileLength = 0;
       string connStr = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString;

        private void addSplash()
        {
            HttpPostedFile uploadFile = FileLogo.PostedFile;
            fileLength = uploadFile.ContentLength;

            if (fileLength == 0)
            {
                string filePath = Server.MapPath(@"\style\img\no-photo-icon.jpg");
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

                FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                fileLength = (Int32)fs.Length;
                Byte[] fileByteArr = new Byte[fileLength];
                fs.Read(fileByteArr, 0, fileLength);

                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into SPLASH (VersionNumber, SplashLabel,LoginID) values (@VersionNumber,@SplashLabel,@LoginID)", conn);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VersionNumber", txtVnum.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SplashLabel", txtSpLabel.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginID", txtYourID.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageData", fileByteArr);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageContentType", "image/jpg");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageSize", fileLength);

                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
                cmd.Dispose();

            }
            else
            {
                Byte[] fileByteArray = new Byte[fileLength];
                Stream streamObject = uploadFile.InputStream;
                streamObject.Read(fileByteArray, 0, fileLength);

                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into SPLASH (VersionNumber, SplashLabel,LoginID) values (@VersionNumber,@SplashLabel,@LoginID)", conn);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VersionNumber", txtVnum.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SplashLabel", txtSpLabel.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginID", txtYourID.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageData", fileByteArray);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageContentType", "image/jpg");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageSize", fileLength);


                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
                cmd.Dispose();
            }
        }

        private void showSplash()
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from SPLASH", conn);

            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
            dt.Load(rdr);
            GridViewAddSplash.DataSource = dt;
            GridViewAddSplash.DataBind();
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }

        private void addMainCat()
        {
        }        
        private void showMainCat()
        {           
        }
        private void addSubCat()
        {            
        }
        private void showSubCat()
        {          
        } 
        private void addBusinessContact()       
        {                                  
        } 
        private void showBusinessContact()
        {
        }
        private void addPersonContact()
        {                    
        } 
        private void showPersonContact()
        {           
        }        
    }
}
```

My other related question, How to create ActiveTabChanged for Ajax tabContainer
[Active_TabChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027097/how-to-create-activetabchanged-for-ajax-tabcontainer)

Answer (score 0):

```
int CurrentTab = TabConAddInfo.ActiveTabIndex;
switch (CurrentTab)
{
case 0:
addSplash();
lblMsgAdd.Text = "Added successfully";
break;
}
etc. You would include that in your btn click event. Obviously I don't know if your TabIndex of zero is the right one to call addSplash() - just call the correct function for each tab.
```

As for the change of tab - are you talking about raising a javascript function?

```
OnClientActiveTabChanged="yourfunction";
```

Comment: Is it a Javascript function? I'm very new to programming and this I haven't learned Ajax but I needed the tabContainer tool to develop an admin panel using VS 2012, C#, .ASP.Net. and also need to create a web service.

Comment: Thanks for giving me the code but since I'm very new, I wouldn't know where I should use your coding. is it right under              protected void btnAddCat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {?  And what do I put between case 0: and break; ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you put OnClientActiveTabChanged="yourfunction" in the code that creates the TabContainer - it will call a javascript function whenever the tab is changed.

Comment: Hi Martin, sorry. I had to sleep coz I'm in New Zealand time. Will try little later and will let you know if it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If I type OnClientActiveTabChanged="yourfunction" in C# code, it asks me to create a class, I did it anyway but is this the right way?? and my TabIndex is Zero. Do do I write your coding above in the class? Thanks for answering the questions from this ignorant.....